# Scheme in Emacs blows off color scheme

Tags: emacs, scheme, color-scheme

When I edit scheme (.scm) files in Emacs, I seem to lose my chosen color theme. I'm on Ubuntu 11.10; Emacs 23.3.2 GTK+ and here's my relevant .emacs for color theming:

```
(require 'color-theme)
(eval-after-load "color-theme"
'(progn
 (color-theme-initialize)
 (setq color-theme-is-global t)
 (color-theme-tm)))
```

The tm theme looks good and is easy on the eyes (warm pastels). But when I load a .scm file, the scheme mode seems to have its own ideas about colors and gives me horrible intense glaring blues and, much worse, glowing red for parens. I can open a .lisp file and it conforms to the tm theme nicely -- as do all other file formats. I've switched over to emacs -nw console with term256 set up ... and that seems to calm down the glow a bit, but in GUI Emacs, it's as if only scheme files throw out the tm theme, throw out even 256 colors to glower viciously at me. Even choosing from GUI Emacs menu choice "Tools/Color Themes" doesn't alter the bad scheme-mode color theme. I also use quack.el, but commented out doesn't seem to influence bad colors.  Is this an omen to switch to Haskell?

Comment: Just heard from N Van Dyke who wrote quack.el. He said to go into quack Options/Customize and change the Fontification from PLT to one of the other two options. This seems to have worked, and it was my mistake not to totally disable quack in my .emacs, which I had not before.... Happy ending.

Comment: You should consider posting this as an answer, so the community knows that the question has been solved.

Comment: Rather than the `require` and `eval-after-load` sequence (which reads pretty strangely), you might use `(when (require 'color-theme nil 'noerror) ...)` to only run your code if the library loaded successfully.

Answer (score 3):

This problem was caused by the Quack plugin. To fix it, click on the Quack menu and go to Options->Customize. Scroll down to Quack Fontify Style, click on Value Menu, and choose either Extended GNU Emacs Style or Emacs Default. Scroll back up, click "Save for future sessions," and Exit.